# Planting Bonsai tree | Unsuccessful

Tags: trees, seeds, bonsai

I bought bonsai tree seeds from Aliexpress. I have planted the seeds in regular soil and kept watering it for about 3 months now. Somehow none of the seed bear any tree.

I heard that bonsai trees can be difficult to grow. But why should it be different then other trees?

The seeds are same as the image below, I planted each seed in Jiffy Peat Pellets.

[image]

Comment: Which plant? Bonsai are just restricted forms of ordinary plants, so what type the seeds are may be important because some  may need cold stratification before  they germinate.

Comment: @Bamboo I ordered assorted Japanese bonsai seeds like maple bonsai tree seeds. I have updated the question with what seeds look like. Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Japanese maple will not germinate unless it has had a cold period. If you don't have the right climate to plant the seeds and leave them out of doors over winter to germinate in spring, you need to keep them in a refrigerator (but not a freezer!) for at least 90 days before you plant them.

Comment: @alephzero I see, I can try that so I should soak them in water and refrigerate them for 3 months?

Comment: Break off the "wings" of the seeds, soak them in water for 24 hours, then mix them with a small amount of *dry* potting compost and put them in a plastic bag in the fridge.

Comment: @alephzero thanks! this makes so much sense. Just two question though, can I seal the plastic bag or it must be open from one side, I googled "wings" of seed, is it the outer layer or the the long tail as in the pic?

Comment: @alephzero coming back to this, I scraped the outer wings and soaked them in water and added small amount of potting compost and had put the plastic bag in the fridge. But still now the seeds havent germinated. What could I have done differently?